# plugin select2 in dom html with jquery (show double interface)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom, jquery-select2

[image]

I use select in html DOM, but why interface selectbox show twice everytime I add dom...?

```
$("#add").click(function () {
   $(".detail").append($(".kolomDetail").html());
   $('.select2').select2();
});
```

My html :
[enter link description here](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1EZ_tKDH8tESWoI4RSWD1ZhSZHkdzgJhMmlkqBtCSvcM/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: Pls share your HTML

Comment: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1EZ_tKDH8tESWoI4RSWD1ZhSZHkdzgJhMmlkqBtCSvcM/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: You have 2 elements having `add` as ID so your handler is triggered 2 times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure your select elements do not have the same ID and change your code so you don't initialize select2 elements multiple times.

```
$("#add").click(function () {
   $(".detail").append($(".kolomDetail").html());  
   $(".detail").find(".select2").select2(); // initialize only the new select element
});
```